# Android Expandable ListView on expand

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to change an imageview within my group row when the group is expanded?

I am looking for a way to do this via the code.

Cheers for any tips

EDIT: This is what I am trying to use at the moment, but it does not swap the image

```
    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int [] [] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
        EMPTY_STATE_SET, //0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET //1
    };

    public View getGroupView (int groupPosition,
        boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = getGroupView( groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
        View ind = v.findViewById(R.id.explist_indicator);
        if(ind != null){
            ImageView indicator = (ImageView) ind;
            indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            int stateSetIndex = ( isExpanded ? 1:0);
            Drawable drawable = indicator.getDrawable();
            drawable.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused by the method code, doesn't this just go into an infinite loop? You are calling `getGroupView` in the first line of `getGroupView`.

Comment: I forgot to put a super. infront of that first getGroupView

Comment: Just tried my answer out and it worked. Try handling the inflation of the `convertView` yourself. Use a `LayoutInflater` if it is null and use it instead of `v`.

Comment: thanks it sure did work. I found a way to do it with the native indicators. This was a work around, but i fixed the original problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. Override `getGroupView` and use the `isExpanded` boolean parameter to identify when the group view is expanded (and set your `ImageView` accordingly).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I mean for an actual ImageView and not the group indicator itself.

Comment: thanks. I have tried this and shall post the code I am using. It does not seem to change when the listview is expanded or collapsed